# (nginx) File field upload progress not working, but upload progress in FileField Sources works

Tags: 7, files

Drupal 7.14, FileField Sources 1.4, Nginx, php cgi. File upload limit 1000MB. Using Chrome as browser

Everything has been configured fine.

I've tested using FileField Sources, upload about 700MB through Remote URL. Everything including the progress bar works without problem, even it takes too long time up be uploaded.

**But when upload from my computer;**

If upload small file, the upload progress is visible, but not showing any progress even the file uploaded as usual.

If upload large file, it will be same as above. But it will timeout (timeout after 30 seconds if using Chrome) (if using Opera, the timeout sometime after 17 seconds, sometime after 5 seconds).

The timeout error in Opera:

```
An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally.
Debugging information follows.
Path: /file/ajax/field_hcuba/und/0/form-j39oCcFwF3Y4J8hBu8A1HHms9oDs3xuhYIgLoZ0MQ2Q
StatusText: n/a
ResponseText: 413 Request Entity Too Large
nginx
ReadyState: undefined
```

The timeout error in Chrome:

```
An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally.
Debugging information follows.
Path: /file/ajax/field_hcuba/und/0/form-1smxhyxT7Xw1F6zjZul2gRxkMI7DNF8pkPRTUyW35SU
StatusText: n/a
ResponseText: 
ReadyState: undefined
```

This only happen in Nginx server. In Apache, all works without problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx doesn't support upload progress in core, you will need to install - http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUploadProgressModule

To show upload progress a webserver should implement - RFC1867

Comment: I've installed what you said. But still not works. Can you share your virtual host configuration? I'm confuse because online tutorial give various different example.

Comment: One more, how to implement RFC1867? (I thought RFC1867 is only required if we use APC for upload progress)

Comment: You dont have to implement RFC1867, it will/should be implemented by your webserver like apache/nginx. Using the above extension nginx becomes compliant, it just doesn't implement it in core. Give me sometime, I'll get you config.